# Using VBA in Excel to create a macro to fetch data between worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sets of data that need to be collated, the first has a list of questions (workbook 1), the second Workbook where those same questions are spread out over 5 sheets with ID numbers associated with them. I need a macro that will take a value from workbook 1, search for it in the entire workbook 2 and then locate its ID value and then copy this value into the first workbook.

I've tried numerous codes but I can't get anything near working, the closest I came was using a index, match function but that only does one column, whereas i need approximately 15 columns (I.e the whole worksheet)

Any help would be great!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can we get to see some code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your Excel workbooks are structured something like the following (based on your description).

**Workbook 1**

```
Sheet 1

    A1 "What is the answer to life and all its questions?"
    A2 "Who is the creator of Linux?"
    A3 "What is your favorite text editor?"
```

**Workbook 2**

```
 Sheet 1

    A1 "What is the answer to life and all its questions?"  B1  103401
    A2 "Who is the creator of Linux"                        B2  104113

 Sheet 2

    A1 "What is your favorite text editor"                  B1  101031
```

We can take the index values from column B of workbook 2 (corresponding to our questions in column A of workbook 1) and copy these to column B of workbook 1. I'll provide a solution of how you could easily do this with cell formulas.

**Workbook 1**

```
Sheet 1

   A1 "What is ..." B1 =Index([workbook2.xlsx]Sheet1!$B$1:$B$100$,
                         Match(A1, [workbook2.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1:$A$100,0))
   A2 "Who is ..."  B2 =Index([workbook2.xlsx]Sheet1!$B$1:$B$100$, 
                         Match(A2, [workbook2.xlsx]Sheet1!A$1:$A$100,0))
   ...
```

You could do the same thing in column C for Sheet 2 of workbook 2

**Workbook 1**

```
Sheet 1

   A1 "What is ..." C1 =Index([workbook2.xlsx]Sheet2!$B$1:$B$100$,
                         Match(A1, [workbook2.xlsx]Sheet2!$A$1:$A$100,0))
   A2 "Who is ..."  C2 =Index([workbook2.xlsx]Sheet2!$B$1:$B$100$, 
                         Match(A2, [workbook2.xlsx]Sheet2!A$1:$A$100,0))
   ...
```

Then one of the columns B-E would contain the ID number and the rest of the columns would contain N/A. Note that I only search the first 100 rows of the first 5 sheets of workbook 2.

Comment: Thanks heaps for that! I used this method and it works well, is there any way to clean up the #N/A values and then create a list of the ID numbers found?

Comment: Figured it out! thanks heaps for the answer once again!